# Django Admin URL Routing Issue

Tags: python, django, url

I've been trying to incorporate my Django app called farms into my current project but for some reason `localhost:8000/admin/` no longer routes to the admin page whenever I try to incorporate it. My urls.py files are as follows:

Main App: urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('farms/', include('farms.urls', namespace='farms'))
]
```

Farms App: urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


app_name = 'farms'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('profile/', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('form/', views.profile_form, name='profile_form'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
]
```

Whenever I try to go to `localhost:8000/admin` Django tries to go to `localhost:8000/admin/profile_form` and produces the following error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/

Django Version: 2.0.2
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['farms.apps.FarmsConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrap4']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Template loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /mnt/d/Projects/hawaiian-soil/farms/templates/admin/profile_form.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /mnt/d/Projects/hawaiian-soil/dep/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/profile_form.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /mnt/d/Projects/hawaiian-soil/dep/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/admin/profile_form.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /mnt/d/Projects/hawaiian-soil/dep/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bootstrap4/templates/admin/profile_form.html (Source does not exist)
```

**Edit:** I apparently solved the problem by switching the order of the paths in the urls.py as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('farms/', include('farms.urls', namespace='farms'))
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]
```

I have no idea why this solves the issue though. Is this simply part of the way Django's url namespacing works or is there another reason?

Comment: This happens when you add 'farms' to the installed apps list in your settings?

Comment: Yes. Apparently switching the entries in urlpatterns solves the issue but I have no idea why